# Execute controller method only if PathVariable contain value within a set of values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it feasible to execute a method in spring controller, only if `PathVariable` value sent by browser matches a set of pre-defined values or defined in a list or set?

For example in following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fruitName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewFruitPage(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String fruitName) { 
    .... 
}
```

to execute only if **Mango**, **Orange** or **Grapes** is passed, in any other case Spring should look for some other controller method, which is also taking some dynamic value after **/** (Root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a regex mapping like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fruitName:Mango|Orange|Grapes}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mango(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String fruitName) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we mention any list or Set also here?

Comment: You welcome, for what concerns your question, regex is your only built-in solution, for constraining a path variable against a list, you would have to register a custom PathMatcher, and implement the wnated

Comment: Is it possible to bring Mango|Orange|Grapes using SPEL, from a properties file?